# Is there a way to display others posts in my post?

Tags: posts

Is there a way I can pull in the content from another post into my own post without writing code?

What I mean is that I have created a post called, "Apple post". I also created a post called, "Orange port". I create a third post called, "Fruit". In the "Fruit" post I want to display the content from "Apple post" and "Orange post".

I also have a blog on another server at a whole other domain that has a "Pear post". I want to pull the content in from that as well.

Can I do this with Wordpress without writing code using short codes or a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Without writing code, no - Wordpress will not do this. Shouldn't require much extra code though. Try creating a page called fruit and on it display all posts on it with a category of fruit (you'd have to check the fruit category on the apple and orange posts).

You can grab text from another site with JavaScript (or maybe php?) or you could do an iframe with the other sites post in it?

Comment: I searched online and there is php code I can write and then there were some posts about short codes. These looked like what I want. I found a plugin that shows all the short codes installed in wordpress and there were like only 3. Like caption for image and something else. It was really disappointing. I found a post on line that listed a bunch of short codes I needed but required creating a plugin with code. I do not want to mess with code!

Comment: Have you thought about using iframes? You could do something like this within your 'Fruit' post: <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe> 

Similar to using a short code I suppose.